# I received the error 'cannot return value referencing local variable docker_client', even though I expected `docker_client` should be moved

Tags: rust

I decided to use rust for one of my pet project to learn this language. But faced with problem when started to write fixture for integration tests.

```
use testcontainers::{clients, Container, RunnableImage};
use testcontainers::clients::Cli;
use testcontainers_modules::postgres::Postgres;

struct Fixture<'a> {
    docker_client: clients::Cli,
    postgres_container: Container<'a, Postgres>,
}

impl<'a> Fixture<'a> {
    fn create_postgres_container(cli: &Cli) -> Container<Postgres> {
        cli.run(RunnableImage::from(Postgres::default()))
    }
    async fn new() -> Self {
        let docker_client: clients::Cli = clients::Cli::default();
        let postgres_container: Container<Postgres> =
            Self::create_postgres_container(&docker_client);
        Self {
            docker_client,
            postgres_container,
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let _ = Fixture::new();
}
```

The compiler throws the following error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `docker_client`
  --> tests/example.rs:18:9
   |
17 |               Self::create_postgres_container(&docker_client);
   |                                               -------------- `docker_client` is borrowed here
18 | /         Self {
19 | |             docker_client,
20 | |             postgres_container,
21 | |         }
   | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

In my understanding, both `docker_client` and `postgres_container` should be both moved to structure and problem should not exist. However, it seems like my understanding is incorrect. I would be grateful for your help.

---

UPDATED

Thanks, @drewtato, for the link. The [article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/6274355) @drewtato provided  suggests quite a few options. I managed to resolve my problem with Pin and Option.

```
use std::marker::PhantomPinned;
use std::pin::Pin;

use futures_util::future::BoxFuture;
use futures_util::FutureExt;
use testcontainers::{clients, Container, RunnableImage};
use testcontainers_modules::postgres::Postgres;

struct Fixture<'a> {
    docker_client: clients::Cli,
    pg_container: Option<Container<'a, Postgres>>,
    _marker: PhantomPinned,
}

impl Fixture<'_> {
    fn new() -> Pin<Box<Self>> {
        let this = Self {
            docker_client: clients::Cli::default(),
            pg_container: None,
            _marker: PhantomPinned,
        };

        let mut boxed = Box::pin(this);
        let ptr: *const clients::Cli = &boxed.docker_client;

        unsafe {
            let postgres_container =
                (*ptr).run(RunnableImage::from(Postgres::default()));
            boxed.as_mut().get_unchecked_mut().pg_container =
                Some(postgres_container);
        };

        boxed
    }
}


async fn with_fixture<F>(f: F) -> Result<(), anyhow::Error>
    where
        F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a Fixture<'a>) -> BoxFuture<'a, Result<(), anyhow::Error>>,
{
    let fixture = Fixture::new();
    f(&fixture).await
}

#[tokio::test]
async fn test_connection() {
    with_fixture(|fixture: &Fixture| async {
        let port = fixture.pg_container.as_ref().unwrap().get_host_port_ipv4(5432);
        println!("{}", &port.to_string());
        Ok(())
    }.boxed()).await.unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Why is `new` flagged as `async` when it doesn't appear to `await` anything? For what it's worth, references end up being a lot of trouble in `async` code unless you can keep them contained to within the async block being run.

Comment: Consider using `Arc<Container<Postgres>>` here instead of a plain reference. This is something you can trivially pass around.

Comment: @tadman That's not going to help here because `posgres_conatiner` borrows from `docker_client`, which is the source of the error.

Comment: If you're willing to change `Container`, it may be possible to fix this, but otherwise it's just https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/6274355

Comment: @cdhowie References to references, oh my.

Comment: @drewtato Thanks! stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/6274355 is exactly what I need.